# Is there a way to convert 32bit ocx files into 64bit ocx without source code

Tags: windows, dll, 32bit-64bit, openedge, ocx

I've a set ocx files which are 32bit.
I am migrating my application to 64bit and I need all these ocx to be converted into 64 bit.

I understand that I cannot load a 32 bit ocxin a 64 bit process.
I don't have the source code.
Is there any way to convert the 32bit ocx into 64bit without source code?
What are my options?

Comment: Not many.  Only possible way to get ahead is to host the DLL in a 32-bit surrogate.  It now runs out-of-process, the COM plumbing takes care of translating 64-bit client calls into 32-bit server calls.  That however requires the proxy and stub for the server, registered for both 32-bit and 64-bit code.  Beyond the trouble of getting the 64-bit proxy, an .ocx does not commonly have them at all since they were meant to be used in UI.  Look at the HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Classes/Interface key for one of the interfaces implemented by the .ocx to see if you have any shot at all.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the magic bullet - but I'm afraid that is not possible.

Depending on what those OCX files do, best solution is to change the ABL application and use .NET controls instead. Those are *typically* bitness-independent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to convert the compiled 32bit ocx to 64bit ocx.  Only if the source code for the 32bit ocx is available it may be able to be ported to 64bit. Is this a third-party ocx, ask the vendor whether they have a 64-bit version.